# Magento 1.9.2.0: Amazon Pay For Europe (version 3.0.10) return error when checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, amazon-payment

I had an error

> Your session has expired. Please sign in again by clicking the Pay
>   with Amazon button.

When I checkout without logging to the shop.

But the request from my customer is that we can still use **Amazon Payment** account event when not logging to any shops.

The thing is I can use the same account with another shop without logging. There is only one shop that requests me to do so.

My step:

> 1. Place an order without logging.
> 2. Click "Amazon Pay" and logging the Amazon Pay account.
> 3. The page was redirected Amazon Checkout Page and had an error
>
> **Your session has expired. Please sign in again by clicking the Pay
>   with Amazon button.**

**How can I purchase with the Amazon Payment without login to the shops?**

Comment: This sounds like a possible whitelist issue with Login with Amazon. Can you confirm that your production domain is whitelisted as an "Allowed JavaScript Origin" in your Login with Amazon application?

Comment: Yes, I did it. Everything is ok In "Amazon Seller Central config" .

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you're using Magestore_Sociallogin extesion, try to disable Magestore_Sociallogin and check Amazon Pay again.

You can fix by moving all content in `<default>` to `<customer_account_login>` and `<customer_account_create>` in sociallogin.xml

I got the same issue with Magento 1.9.2 and Amazon 3.0.12, and this works with me.